# How to download pronunciation audio from dictionary.cambridge.org

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, html-parsing

How to download pronunciation audio from [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://stackoverflow.com)
[Help me to download this audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSNRg.png)
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ                                    ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
I without ideas what to do.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 0):

You can use console application [cambridge-dictionary-audio](https://github.com/astrosander/cambridge-dictionary-audio).

You may download [.exe file](https://github.com/astrosander/cambridge-dictionary-audio/releases/tag/cambridge-dictionary) from releases  or make [python installation](https://github.com/astrosander/cambridge-dictionary-audio#python-installation-).

On the github you will sea all instractions.